# Query slow with Order by clause in Range-List Partition Table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, query-optimization

Hi I created a FACT TABLE with Range-List Partition.

The range partition is for months DATE_REG ( 01/2013, ... ,01/2014, 02/2014, ....).
The list subpartition is for strings TYPE_R ( 'A', 'B', 'C').

the main index is

CREATE INDEX INX_DATE_REG ON FACT_TABLE (DATE_REG)

My query is

```
Select
.... 
FROM FACT_TABLE 
INNER JOIN A ...
INNER JOIN B ...
INNER JOIN C ...
INNER JOIN D ...
INNER JOIN E ...
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/01/2013' -- DD/MM/YYYY
AND DATE_REG < '01/01/2014'
AND TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

When I ommit ORDER BY Clause the execution time is 2.35 sec, but when I consider Order By the time change to 125 sec.

I know that this problem is because when order by is active, it through all the rows, and the Range of DATE_REG is in multiple partitions.

My question is : How could I optimize this query?

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

When my query is (Case 1) :

```
Select
ft.x,
ft.y,
...
ft.xxxxx
FROM FACT_TABLE ft 
INNER JOIN A ...
INNER JOIN B ...
INNER JOIN C ...
INNER JOIN D ...
INNER JOIN E ...
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/01/2013' -- DD/MM/YYYY
AND DATE_REG < '01/01/2014'
AND TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

The time is 15 sec.

When my query is (Case 2) :

```
Select
ft.x,
ft.y,
...
ft.xxxxx,
E.abc
FROM FACT_TABLE ft 
INNER JOIN A ...
INNER JOIN B ...
INNER JOIN C ...
INNER JOIN D ...
INNER JOIN E ...
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/01/2013' -- DD/MM/YYYY
AND DATE_REG < '01/01/2014'
AND TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

The time is 150 sec. abd is a Column which hasn't an index.

When my query is (Case 3) :

```
Select
*
FROM FACT_TABLE ft 
INNER JOIN A ...
INNER JOIN B ...
INNER JOIN C ...
INNER JOIN D ...
INNER JOIN E ...
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/01/2013' -- DD/MM/YYYY
AND DATE_REG < '01/01/2014'
AND TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

The time is 17 sec.

Sort becomes slow when the query called an extra column from another table, but when I called all columns (case 3) the time is less than the case 2.

Explain Plan _ Case 1
[image: Explain Plan _ Case 1]

*Explain Plan _ Case 2*
[image: Explain Plan _ Case 2]

In this moment each partition contains 2.5 millions of rows.

Comment: Is "seg" an abbreviation for "seconds" (which would normally be abbreviated "sec")?  Are you measuring the time required to fetch the first row?  Or the time required to fetch the last row?  How many rows does your query return?

Comment: Sorry, I corrected. My tests were for the first row. Were approximately 8000/16000000 rows. I just added new information. thanks

Comment: Measuring the time required to fetch the first row makes the comparison unreasonable.  In order to return the first row when you specify an `order by`, all the rows need to be fetched and sorted.  In order to return the first row without an `order by`, Oracle doesn't need to materialize the result set first.  None of the three queries you posted, though, lack an `order by`.  Query 1 and 2 appear to be identical.  Query 3 appears only to differ in the list of columns in the `select` list.  Is that really the only difference?

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that the second query becomes slow when adding a column in another table which is not a foreign key. y question is, is it possible that by just adding a column change much over time? and when I consult all columns the time is shorter than when specific the columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `where` clause doesn't make sense to me:

```
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/01/2013' AND -- DD/MM/YYYY
      DATE_REG >= '01/11/2013' AND
      TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

This is equivalent to:

```
WHERE DATE_REG >= '01/11/2013' AND
      TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

I'm uncomfortable with the use of the "DD/MM/YYYY" format, so I think this would be better expressed as:

```
WHERE DATE_REG >= to_date('01/11/2013', 'DD/MM/YYYY') AND
      TYPE_R = 'B'
ORDER BY DATE_REG ASC
```

As for the performance of your query with `order by`, it is probably due to the volume of data.  Sorting does take time and it is not clear how you could arrange for Oracle to use an index in this case.

Comment: Sorry It's AND DATE_REG < '01/01/2014' for the second constraint.

Comment: @JohnPortella . . . You still are not using Oracle's standard format for dates, so the query looks very suspicious to me.